# schema design - best practise for storing survey data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, schema

**Background:**
I want to create a table for storing the questions and user answer in survey for research purpose.

The questions are multiple choices but only one answer can be selected.
The questions can be added or hided by users.
The questions are the same for every user.

Also, NO interviewer information is required to store because it is anonymous.

There is no absolute answer for the question because the choices are static for every question.

**Table**

```
Survey
-id(PKey)
-submittedDate

Question
-id(PKey)
-questionText

Answer
-id(PKey)
-answerText
```

**Access Pattern**

1.Find a survey with certain id with its questions and answers.
2.Calculate the distribution of the answer for certain questions, e.g. 50% people select answer a, 25% people select answer b for question 1.

**Example**

```
                                         1     2     3     4     5
1. How much water do you drink today                 ✓
2. How many apples do you eat today                        ✓
```

**My question**
I have a rough design of the table and some fields, but I want to get some insight of how to relating these tables, and how should I design the schema using these 3 tables.

**Update**
Seems the Survey Table has been misunderstood.
Here is more concrete example.

```
Survey id 123
                                                 1     2     3     4     5
1. How much water do you drink today(questionId 1)                 ✓
2. How many apples do you eat today(questionId 2)                  ✓



Survey id 124
                                                 1     2     3     4     5
1. How much water do you drink today(questionId 1)                 ✓
2. How many oranges do you eat today(questionId 3)      ✓
```

questionId 1 belongs to Survey id 123 and 124.
Survey id 123 have questionId 1 and 2.
So it is N-to-M relationship?

Comment: Are the questions multiple-choice?  Or fill in?  Where are the ids for joining the tables?  Eg: `survey_id` needs to be in `Questions`, correct?

Comment: the questions are multiple-choice as the example

Comment: @Rick James For your second question, I am not sure how should I put the foreign key, as the relationship between these 3 tables seems N-to-M

Comment: They feel like 1:N -- 1 survey has N questions; each question has N answers.   Abdulmohsen points out how to implement 1:N.

Comment: @Rick James Please see my update

Comment: OK, now I see the many-to-many between surveys and questions.  That needs a new table to bridge them.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Surveys (
    sid ... AUTO_INCREMENT,
    other info about the survey (date, who took it, etc)
    PRIMARY KEY(sid),
    maybe other indexes
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE S_Q (
    -- no AUTO_INCREMENT needed
    sid ...,  -- not AUTO_INCREMENT
    qid ...,  -- not AUTO_INCREMENT
    answer VARCHAR(...),       -- the actual answer (no need to normalization)
    PRIMARY KEY(sid, qid),
    INDEX(qid, sid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Questions (
    qid ... AUTO_INCREMENT,
    question_text  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(qid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

// This table may be unnecessary:
CREATE TABLE Answers (
    -- no AUTO_INCREMENT needed
    qid ...,
    answer VARCHAR(...),
    answer_description  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(qid, answer)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

(All columns should probably be `NOT NULL`.)

`answer` is the actual answer.  It is short enough and self-descriptive enough not to need a lookup via an id.

Comment: for S_Q table, you mean answerId instead of answer, right?

Comment: @CCCC - Based on your example, the possible answers are small numbers; there does not need to be an "id" in the way.  If your survey includes "Favorite color", then the answer (not answer_id) can be "blue" or "red" or ... -- a `VARCHAR`

Comment: That is, "number of glasses" begs for a number; such does not need a lookup.  I am further suggesting the same for "favorite color".  It may be presented as a multiple-choice, but it may as well be stored as a string.

Comment: And what about the guy that guzzles "> 8 glasses" per day?

Comment: And "0" seems like a valid answer for your sample questions.  And "no favorite" for my qolor question.

Comment: @ Rick James the answer and question are just an example. Actually the question can be what is your favourite color and the answer can be [blue,red,white] etc

Comment: An FK is a combination of 2 things:  an index (which I have provided) and a 'constraint' that does some consistency checking.

Comment: Sure, you _could_ have an `answer_id`.  But my experience with implementing "tags", and a few other things, leads me to suggest that it is unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add to FKs on the question table which Survey it belongs to and on the Answer table for which Question this answer.

**Survey**

- id(PKey)
- submittedDate

**Question**

- id(PKey)
- questionText
- Survey_id(FK)

**Answer**

- id(PKey)
- answerText
- Question_id (FK)

Comment: but a question can be belong to multiple surveys.

Comment: Also, Question and Survey are N-to-N relationship

Comment: @CCCC In which case have a separate table which records which question(s) belong(s) to which survey(s)

Comment: correct if the relation N-to-M we need to represent this relation as a table contains the PK of each table